# how to have 2 apps using appdatapreferences-android on same device?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm using https://github.com/googledrive/appdatapreferences-android to synchronize preferences data. I got the example working at https://github.com/googledrive/appdatapreferences-android-quickstart.

Then I started implementing it in my own app. When I tried to install I got the error: Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER. This error indicates that I had 2 providers with the same authority on the same device (which is NOT allowed). In this case the authority is "com.google.drive.appdatapreferences"

So I changed the authority in my app (manifest) to be distinct. But then the sync doesn't work anymore since the value is hard-coded in com.google.drive.appdatapreferences.AppdataPreferencesSyncManager.AUTHORITY = "com.sourcebrewery.appdatapreferences"

I really don't want to change the library code in appdatapreferences-android.

Is there any way around this? ...otherwise only 1 app per device can use this library :(